# Copying Azure blob storage blobs via CloudBlockBlov.StartCopyAsync very very slow / CopyStatus.State remains Invalid

Tags: azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

We have a process, where customers send blobs to a blob storage container, followed by a message on an Azure service bus that triggers preprocessing and copying of these blobs to their final destination (another storage account).

The preprocessing is mostly determining of the container for the final storage, and is less relevant here.

The process of copying the blobs to their final destination is implemented using durable functions. The StartCopyAsync() is invoked on the source blob, and then the copy state is monitored using an activity trigger that periodically (each 5 seconds) fetches the attributes of the destination blob, and checks the copy state. That periodical check is implemented using a timer on the orchestration context.

What we now notice in our **production** environment, is that the check on the copy state of the destination blob keeps returning a Copystatus.State = CopyStatus.Invalid or CopyStatus.Pending. This goes on for the full 5 minutes until the function execution times out. When we check on the destination blob afterwards, we see indeed that the copy was completed about 7 minutes after it was initiated. This is for a file of less than 0.5 MB! On the next retry of the function, we get an exception stating that a copy state is pending.

When we try to figure out what is going on in our **local / dev environment**, we see that the copy status keeps on returning state Invalid, long after we see in blob storage, that the copy was completed almost instantanuously (and in this case for a 3 MB file!).

So depending on the environment, we see a different behavior:

In production, the copying takes way too long for a small blob copy.
In development / local, the copy status keeps returning Invalid, long after the copy was completed according to the attributes on the destination blob.

Any hint on what we do wrong here? We should note here that in our production environment, customers upload blobs and associated service bus messages at a high rate while boarding. Is the blob copy mechanism less suited for these scenarios?

Comment: Are source and destination storage accounts two separate accounts in your production environment? Are they in the same region?

Comment: @GauravMantri same subscription, same resource group, yes

Comment: But are they in the same region? You could have resources in same resource group but they can be in different regions.

Comment: Sorry yes, my answer was incomplete. All in region West-Europe.